# How change time of screen activity in android app (always active, active while charging, normal)

Tags: java, android, layoutparams

I am writing app in android and I need to change time of screen activity. In settings I have 3 possible variants:

1) screen always active;
2) screen always active while charging;
3) normal screen activity (using default android user settings)

For first variant I found solution:

```
 getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

But if I understand right it works just for one Activity. How I can do it for all activities in my app? And what I should do for second and third variants? Can you help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution can be is to make a custom activity for that variant. After that u can extend all your other activities from the custom one. It will inherit everything from the upper class so also this part.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```